# Symfony - undefined variable twig

Tags: php, variables, twig

I made a list of items to render from db and in other examples it works just fine, but sometimes in trwos error

> Variable "ticket" does not exist.
>   and I can't figure out what am I doing wrong..

```
/**
 * @Route("/ticket-list", name="purchased_tickets_list")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function ticketListAction(Request $request)
{

    $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Tickets')
        ->findAll();

    $build['ticket'] = $query;

    return $this->render('@AdminTemplates/pages/purchased-tickets-list.html.twig', $build);
}
```

and in my twig

```
 {% for p in ticket %}
      <tbody>
       <tr>
         <td>{{ p.id }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.buyersName }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.ticketType }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.playName }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.theaterName }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.time }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.date|date("m/d/Y") }}</td>
         <td class="text-primary"><td>{{ p.price|date('H:i:s') }}</td>
         <td>{{ p.price }}</td>  
       </tr>
 </tbody>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You need to pass an array with the key (your Twig var) and the value. So in your case : replace `$build` in your return by `array('ticket' => $query)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass ticket -

see below example of sending var:

Controller file:

```
return $this->render('category/list.html.twig', ['categories' => $categories]);
```

twig:

```
{% for value in categories %}
    {# rest of code #}
{% endfor %}
```

update based on comments:

try this:

Controller

```
$builds = array('foo' => 'one', 'bar' => 'two');
return $this->render('category/list.html.twig', array('ticket' => $builds));
```

twig file:

```
{{ dump(ticket) }}
```

dump is a var_dump in a really pretty human-readable format. If nothing comes through maybe you're in production mode, in that case try running (after changes) in terminal:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

Comment: @developsss can you update code in question to reflect changes please? (note: the `[]` declaration of array is PHP7 - maybe use `array('ticket' => $build)`

Comment: In all type of examples I tried so far, trows same error.. Variable "ticket" does not exist.